# Trigger function on a global $.ajax event for a specific ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got 3-4 ajax calls that will be made at some point.
For one of those calls I'd like to trigger a function on the `ajaxSend` event which is global. This specific ajax call is not necesserily the first or last one in the sequence. It seems that if I attach the `ajaxSend` event to the `$(document)`, my function will fire every other time that an ajaxSend event occurs. Here's what my code looks like:

```
//ajax call one
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    data: myData
});

//ajax call two <- let's say I'd like to fire ajaxSpecificFunc() here
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    data: myData
});

//ajax call three
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    data: myData
});


function ajaxSpecificFunc(){
    $(document).on("ajaxSend", function() {
        //Some code that should only happen on ajaxSend but for only one ajax call
    });
}
```

EDIT: I am aware of `global:false` property for ajax, but do not wish to use it, as this would mean I would have to modify every new ajax call in the future to have `ajaxSpecificFunc()` continue to fire for the one specific ajax call

Comment: Why not just add the `ajaxSpecificFunc` into the `always` or `beforeSend` callback for your specific AJAX call?

Comment: You have to bind global ajax method for all requests and filter it out to use it for only specific request regarding which specific data/url/ajax option your are passing to this request. Now if all your ajax requests are similar like supposes your posted code, this wouldn't make sense anyway...

Answer (score 2):

You can add `beforeSend` in `jQuery.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myUrl,
    data: myData,
    beforeSend: ajaxSpecificFunc
});
```

As noted by **A.Wolff**, this way if we call this function it will bind the `ajaxsend` for each call. Instead you can remove it and just do the specific ones like:

```
function ajaxSpecificFunc(jqXHR, settings){
   // you can work with the jqXhr and settings
}
```

Comment: You will bind event on each call and anyway, i'm quite sure it would be to late for the first one

Comment: @A.Wolff you picked it up.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't bind the handler directly to the ajax call, and want to use the global handlers only then you can check the setting object to see whether the ajax call is your targeted on and if so then call your stuff

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqXHR, settings) {
  console.log('send', settings);
  if (settings.url == 'myurl') {
    //then do your stuff
  }
})
```

Note: But this might become an overkill, and you should try to do it specific to your ajax call